# Cannot display JSON data from API on antd table

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, antd

My parent component is:

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {data: []}
}
componentWillMount(){
  this.props.getData(); //makes api call
  this.setState({data: this.props.data}); //get data stored in the store
}
render(){
  const columns ={ //columns here}
  return(
    <Tables
      dataSource = {this.state.data}
      columns = {this.columns}
    />
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.data,
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getData: () => dispatch(getData()),
})
```

I do get data when I console it, but when I try to set state of data with the data props. It says data.slice is not a function.

//saga

```
export function* getData(action){
  try{
  const data = yield call(axios.get, 'http://localhost:4000/data');
  console.log(data);
  if (data) {
    yield put(updateData(data.data));
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

//actions

```
export const updateData = data => ({
  type: UPDATE_DATA,
  data
});
```

//reducers

```
export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({});
export const updateData = (state, action) => {
  console.log('reducers', action.data);
  return { ...state, ...action.data };
};

const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [UPDATE_DATA]: updateData,
};

export default createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, ACTION_HANDLERS);
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong while setting the state. I cannot seem to find out the errors.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState({data: this.props.data}); //get data stored in the store`

The data is not yet there. If you *really* wants to set the state to use the prop data, you need to update your state in your `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` lifecycle function, not on `componentDidMount()`.

#### Analyzing this function

`componentWillMount(){
  this.props.getData(); //makes api call
  this.setState({data: this.props.data}); //get data stored in the store
}`

when you call `getData()`, the browser will do its thing and your redux state will be updated *eventually*, so, when the second line is called, the data is not yet there.

You could use some promises and/or `async/await` functions, but you don't really need to. You can use the regular component lifecycle functions and, event better, you can use `this.props.data` and not have an internal state at all.

Comment: Just FYI componentWillReceiveProps is going to be depracted. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops instead. Also https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html.